# How do you dispose or free a file buffer in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management, buffer

I have an object that contains a temporary file buffer:

```
console.log(myObject)
// output:
{
  path: "/some/path",
  someBuffer: <Buffer fe d8 ff db 00 43 28 ae 6e 78 8c ee 64 a0 8c 82 8c b4 aa a0 be f0 ff ff f0 dc dc f0 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ... >
}
```

After I'm done doing some processing on this buffer I want to release it. How exactly do you release or free a buffer from memory? Just set to `null`?

```
myObject.someBuffer = null
```

Is that all there is to it? Did that free up the memory that the buffer was taking up?

Comment: I'm assuming that myObject will still be around though. I'll use it for other things in my app. It's just the buffer that will be set to `null`. So to understand better, are you saying that when you set something to `null` that means the next time garbage collection happens, that it will release that memory?

Comment: You could take a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management.

Comment: You can set it to `null` just to be sure, but if `myObject` is not reachable (for example it's in a function's scope) there is no need for this either.